# python save array to csv with different length

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, csv

this is my code

```
import numpy
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10] ])
numpy.savetxt("a.csv", a, fmt="%d", delimiter=",")
```

I run it, but it report error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1422, in savetxt
    v = format % tuple(row) + newline
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/csvTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", a,fmt="%d", delimiter=",")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1426, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%d')
```

after i try this code

```
import numpy
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ])
numpy.savetxt("a.csv", a, fmt="%d", delimiter=",")
```

it can work, so how do i to solve this problem?
can i save different array length with csv?

Comment: look at `a`.  Is it a 2d array, with consistent rows and columns?  Or a 1d array containing lists?  I suggest forgetting numpy, and writing the list of lists directly to the file.  Use regular python code to format the lists as you want.  By the way, how do you expect to read this file?

Comment: Show the file text that you hope to generate.

Comment: Actually this issue i am not very care, it just from my curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [98]: alist=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10] ]
In [99]: alist
Out[99]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

formatting a display string:

```
In [100]: astr = []
     ...: for row in alist:
     ...:     col = ', '.join(['%d'%i for i in row])
     ...:     astr.append(col)
     ...: astr = '\n'.join(astr)
In [101]: astr
Out[101]: '1, 2, 3, 4\n5, 6\n7, 8, 9, 10'
In [102]: print(astr)
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6
7, 8, 9, 10
```

and with a file write:

```
In [104]: with open('test.txt','w') as f:
     ...:     for row in alist:
     ...:         print(', '.join(['%d'%i for i in row]), file=f)
     ...: 
In [105]: cat test.txt
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6
7, 8, 9, 10
```

If we try to write it as an array:

```
In [106]: arr = np.array(alist)
<ipython-input-106-3fd8e9bd05a9>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  arr = np.array(alist)
In [107]: arr
Out[107]: 
array([list([1, 2, 3, 4]), list([5, 6]), list([7, 8, 9, 10])],
      dtype=object)
```

This is a 1d array containing lists.  If we write with '%s' format the lists will be formatted as standard lists:

```
In [108]: np.savetxt('test.csv',arr, fmt='%s')
In [109]: cat test.csv
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Neither is good csv reading material.  The `[]` interfere with parsing a line.  The unequal lines require special handling, either rejection as being the wrong length, or filled with extra values.

Comment: thx answer me how to solve, it a little complex...
but it only save string?
can change it to int?

Comment: The '%s' turns anything into a string.  But all the other Python formats are available,  And if you are writing directly (not with `savetxt`) you can use the new `format` tool.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the array as string can resolve the issue.

```
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10] ])
numpy.savetxt("a.csv", a, fmt="%s", delimiter=",")
```